# WebSphere Server Error equires the WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 Feature Pack for Web Services installed on the server

Tags: websphere

I am getting bellow error when starting the server WAS 6.1. which has web service component. Based on the error message i could understand i need to install feature pack to fix this error.

Publishing failed
  WebSphere Server Error
    WebSphere Server Error
      The project, , requires the WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 Feature Pack for Web Services installed on the server.
      The WebSphere Application Server profile also needs to be augmented with Feature Pack for Web Services enabled.
      To get the feature pack, see http://www.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/support/

but which version of feature pack should i patch it with.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to continue to use WAS 6.1, which has been withdrawn from service for a few years, you should use the last published WAS fixpack and the last published Web Services Feature Pack.  That's 6.1.0.47 and 6.1.0.45 respectively which should be pretty clear from the link in your error message.

But really you should get off of 6.1 as a priority.